# Kaminari paginating arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

In rails 4.0.0.

Why does this work

```
@employees = Employee.where(:club_id => session[:club_id]).page(params[:page])
```

but not this?

```
@payments = Payment.where(:club_id => session[:club_id], 
                           :trading_date => trading_date).page(params[:page])
```

On the second form I get an array error. I know how to fix it but I am perplexed as to why this occurs?

my error is this

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `page' for #<Array:0x007ff72845b380>):
app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:30:in `index'
```

Comment: Post the exact error you are getting.

Comment: edited to show error.

Comment: is there any relation between `club_id` and `trading_date` means the conditions u have written are connected like (A and B) or (A or B) manner. if its logically connected then i think this should work well for you.


    '@payments = Payment.where(:club_id => session[:club_id]) and/or :trading_date => trading_date)
  .page(params[:page])'

Comment: No relation, they are just separate columns in the payments tables. In this case, the club_id is read from the session and the trading date from params. This will not work as above unless I use the array helper in kaminari as @payments = Kaminari.paginate_array(myarray).page(params[:page])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you dont want to do

```
@payments = Payment.where(:club_id => session[:club_id])
  .where(:trading_date => trading_date)
  .page(params[:page])
```